# How to deal with web fonts acting up?

Tags: google-chrome, printing, webfonts

How to deal with web fonts acting up sometimes in Print mode – some chunks of text not being displayed?

It's not that easy to reproduce it, but it happens now and then, in Google Chrome (Windows).

When it happens, one opens a page that has a hidden/toggle-able section in a smaller font (but same font face as the main text), presses [Ctrl]+[p] to open the print preview. In the print mode, the hidden section gets displayed disregarding the toggling state.

And in some cases, parts of that section (in Noto Serif font) are invisible/white, but takes up space. The other parts – in another webfont and in Noto Serif italics (the same size) – are visible all right.

If one then closes the print preview and re-opens, something has refreshed, and everything is visible again.

An example of the broken text: [image: print preview screenshot]

Comment: Interesting problem. Can you show the relevant code for this section? (html?, css?, javaScript?) What do you mean by "invisible/white" – is the text white on a white background and remains selectable, or is it just not there? Also, do you have a separate print-media css file?

Comment: Yes, we have a separate print-media CSS, but it doesn't contain any font style changes, mainly just hides unwanted elements (https://juristavards.lv/css/print.css).

The vanished text seems to be non-selectable. If printed to a PDF, the characters are not there at all (they are absent also in the text extracted from the PDF). Still, it takes up space, as you can see in the screen-shot.

The code is something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/janise/n6tg3dso/2/

Comment: Everything seems to work well in your JSfiddle. Printing from the fiddle in Chrome prints the whole fiddle, but still shows the _raksta atsauces_ perfectly. Other browsers focus on the html frame properly and also print everything very well. If you're still having trouble, can you point us to sandbox link?

Comment: Well, as I said, it's not easy to reproduce. It seems to not happen on one computer, happens on the other. And everything is all right for some time, than the text breaks. If you refresh and try again, the text is fine. When you get back after some time, it may be broken again, it may not be broken. This was just so you can see the related code being involved. Unfortunately, I cannot give you the actual page, it's not publicly available.

Comment: This seems to be the same sort of problem described in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39364259/chrome-print-preview-doesnt-load-media-only-print-font-face
And the work-around with the invisible text sample with the same font seems to be working, too.

Comment: @JanisElmeris I'm glad to hear that you worked this out. I wanted to help, but I got ploughed-under at work. Thanks for the update.

Comment: OK, another update. Unfortunately, that fix helped in some cases, but not in other. Maybe depends on the amount of text present. We decided to display the text initially and then hide on after page load. This seems to work. And the flicker is not a big deal as the hidden content is located below the fold.