# Google font prevents selecting text when printing Vue app to pdf

Tags: css, vue.js, google-font-api

I'm creating a simple Vue app that I will use to generate my CV in a PDF format. I have added google font Montserrat into this project, and when I print this page to file (CTRL + P in Firefox), the text cannot be selected, its like everything is an image.

I started debugging and it seems to happen when I use an imported font. Here is a codepen that can demonstrate what happens https://codepen.io/phlame-/pen/NWNYbyb

**How to replicate**: Open the pen in Firefox, and print the page to file (CTRL + P). Save and open the file. The second paragraph is selectable as its Arial, but the first one is not (which is Montserrat).

It seems like if you try to do this in Chrome nothing is selectable, but I would like it to work at least in 1 browser - since only I will use it to generate PDFs.

I've tried to import the font through a link tag instead of @import in CSS, tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45883930/3250336), tried different Google fonts (Roboto and Lato), this:

```
@media print {
  * {
    user-select: text !important;
  }
}
```

All producing same results - unselectable text. Which becomes selectable with a default font...

To be clear: the font **renders** in the PDF, everything looks as it should, but the text is NOT selectable when clicking and dragging over the text

Has anyone had experience with this? Any help is appreciated

Comment: I've had some experience with it. I think the problem is that print only has access to your local fonts, so it treats the text as an image. I haven't tested it, but  downloading Montserrat and installing it on your machine is likely to resolve your problem. If so, please let me know and I'll write it up in more detail as an answer.

Comment: Hi @BobRodes thanks for the suggestion. I just tried to add the font with `npm i typeface-montserrat` and then `require('typeface-montserrat');` in App.vue. The font is loaded but the printed pdf file still cannot have text selected. Is this how you imagined to download the font?

Comment: I don't know whether `npm` works or not. If you managed to install it as a system font, then you should be able to open a text editor or something and see it in the list of fonts you can use. [Here's](https://flourishonline.com.au/download-google-fonts-mac-pc/) a set of directions on how to download and install a google font, both for Mac and PC. I don't think you should have to require a typeface, either, if it's installed as a local font. (Don't know vue, do you have to require every font you use?)

Comment: You the man/woman! Installed it on my machine and after a restart its working perfectly now, thank you!! If you have time you can write up an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: Done. I'm a man, btw. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same thing once using Overlock on a resume page. The problem is that the browser print utility doesn't recognize fonts that your page downloads on the fly using `link` tags, as it is customary to do with google fonts. It can only recognize system fonts, meaning the ones you have installed on the machine you're running the `Print` from.

If some text on your web page is using a font that isn't on your installed system font list, then you won't be able to save it as text in your PDF file. When the print utility encounters such, it treats it as an image.

Different OSes have different ways of examining what fonts you have on your machine ("Font Manager" in Windows, "Font Book" in Mac OS). You can google how to see what fonts you have installed on your machine, and you should find that Montserrat isn't one of them.

To fix this, all you need to do is install the Montserrat google font on your machine. [Here](https://flourishonline.com.au/download-google-fonts-mac-pc/) is one set of directions on how to do that. Once you've done that, you'll need to restart your browser.

Comment: I'd just like to add for future readers that this solves my use case where only I would need to print pages to PDFs. Unfortunately this probably won't work if the site is public facing, and you would like your visitors to print the page to a PDF with a font they don't have on their machine. Text will still be visible and probably rendered by the custom font, but it will be treated as an image.

Comment: @Phlame Well, no. You can install fonts on your website, too. See https://robertrodes.com, which uses IBM Plex fonts. (Just tested it, and IBM Plex text is treated as text.) All the font files are in a folder called `public_html/fonts`, which is how bluehost lets you install fonts. I have only used bluehost, but I'd be very surprised if other hosts (e.g. GoDaddy) didn't allow you to install fonts.